# Custom name foreign key in Rails causing 'ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, foreign-keys

I have a `Book` model and i have a `User` model. I am trying to create a new column called `author_id` in the `books` table which will actually be a foreign key to the `users` table.

I followed [this article by Joshua Frankel](http://joshfrankel.me/blog/custom-named-belongs_to-associations-in-rails-with-foreign-key-constraints/). But i am getting the following error

> ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR`

I am Using Rails4.2

---

db/migrate/20191112111409_add_author_to_books.rb:

```rb
class AddAuthorToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_reference :books, :author, references: :users, index: false
    commit_db_transaction
    add_index :books, :author_id, algorithm: :concurrently
    add_foreign_key :books, :users, column: :author_id
  end

  def down
    remove_column :books, :author_id
  end
end
```

app/models/book.rb:

```rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: :User, foreign_key: :author_id
end
```

app/models/user.rb:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, foreign_key: :author_id
end
```

Error in Rails console:

```rb
> user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
> book = FactoryBot.create(:book)
> book.author = user
> book.save
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "books" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_13be98de92"
DETAIL:  Key (author_id)=(1) is not present in table "users".
: UPDATE "books" SET "author_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "books"."id" = $3
from ~/.ruby-gemset/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:602:in `exec_prepared'
Caused by PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "books" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_13be98de92"
DETAIL:  Key (author_id)=(1) is not present in table "users".

from ~/.ruby-gemset/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:602:in `exec_prepared'
>
```

Answer (score 1):

### I found the issue. It has to do with Schemas in Postgres.

I use the Apartment gem for tenancy in the Postgres Database. In my case, the `books` table is tenanted. However, the `users` table is not tenanted - they are universal. Meaning, the `user` exists in `public` schema but the `book` exists in (let's say) `Malaysia` schema.

So, when we are trying to save `book.save!`, the `books` table (which is in `Malaysia` schema) checks for a user with id 1 in `users` table of the same schema (i.e. `Malaysia` schema). However, since my users actually exist in `public` schema, it thinks there is no user with id 1 (as it's looking for it in the `Malaysia` schema only).

Then i came across this [known issue in Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/397) about Foreign Keys across Schemas.

---

### How did i fix it?

- I rolled back my db migration ONE step to basically to revert my changes by removing the new `author_id` column.
- Then removed the `add_foreign_key` statement from the migration file so that the Postgres table doesn't create any db-level foreign key association.
- Then ran the migration again.

So now, I do have a new column called `author_id` (which is also indexed) but it doesn't have a DB-level foreign key to the `users` table. Then the spec passed gracefully.

Thus, it's not really a first-class db-level foreign key anymore. It just relies on the Rails associations that are defined in the model to achieve a *"foreign-key-sque"* behavior as we desire - works nicely.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the issue here. I left a simplified migration that might help next time you need to add a concurrent index, reference, and a <b>foreign_key</b> to a custom named column: http://joshfrankel.me/blog/custom-named-belongs_to-associations-in-rails-with-foreign-key-constraints/#disqus_thread

Comment: Thanks @JoshFrankel . Appreciate the help :)